# asterisk From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown

Tags: freepbx

Пытаюсь настроить звонки во freepbx. Один канал настроил, все прекрасно работает. Пробую настраивать канал аналогичным способом — выдает лог:

> SIP/2.0 200 OK
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
>   From: "Unknown" ;tag=as4e38eb0d
>   To: ;tag=as7655d350

Если работающий транк поменять на другой (с теми же настройками), то ошибка аналогичная.